# Make element not move with other elements until mouse moves off

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry if this has already been asked, I couldn't find anything. I've been trying to find ways for the past while to make a dropdown menu not move when the element it's attached to changes size. I have a dropdown menu like this:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn"><div id="imageWidth" class="imageWidth"><input type="image" id="imageclick" src="./images/Clicktoadd.png" accept="image/*" class="imageclick"/></div></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a class="font fontsize1"><p class="inline fontsize2">Image size: </p><input type="range" min="50" max="500" value="150" class="slider" id="myRange"></a>
        <a class="font fontsize1"><p class="inline fontsize2">Font size: </p><input type="range" min="10" max="80" value="20" class="slider" id="myRange2"></a>
        <a class="font fontsize1"><p class="inline fontsize2">Text: </p><input class="font textinput" type="text"  maxlength="25"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And what the sliders with "Image size" and "Font size" do is change the size of the image input with and ID of imageclick.

Now, the dropdown menu has no problems. it works great. But since the first slider changes the size of the image, It has been a slight problem that when the image changes size, the slider moves. This means that it just shoots straight off the screen and you are no longer dragging the slider, and you can barely move it at all.

So. what I want to happen is I want once the dropdown menu opens when you start moving the slider, the dropdown stays exactly where it is, and then only moves to the bottom of the image when you hover back over the image.

I would prefer it not to be in JQuery and only pure JavaScript, but I could either convert JQuery or just use google hosted libraries(or whatever it's called).

The way I change the size of the image is just by using something like this:

```js
document.getElementById("myRange").oninput = function() {
    document.getElementById("imageWidth").style.width = this.value + "px";
}
```

Sorry if I'm not being really clear, this is only like my third post, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! What I did was something like this:

```js
            var menu1 = document.getElementById('html');
            var innermenu1 = document.getElementById('dropdown-content');

            const isHover = e => e.parentElement.querySelector(':hover') === e;    

            const myDiv = document.getElementById('dropdown');
            var hovered, tempvalue;
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', function checkHover() {
                hovered = isHover(myDiv);
                if (hovered !== checkHover.hovered) {
                    console.log(hovered ? 'hovered' : 'not hovered');
                    checkHover.hovered = hovered;
                    if(hovered ? 'hovered' : 'not hovered'=='hovered') {
                        tempvalue = (document.getElementById("myRange").value / 32);
                        innermenu1.style.top = ((parseInt(tempvalue, 10) - (parseInt(menu1.scrollTop, 10)/32)) + (document.getElementById("myRange").value/1)) + 'px';
                    }
                }
            });

            window.onscroll = function (e) {
                if(hovered) {
                    innermenu1.style.top = (parseInt(tempvalue, 10) - (parseInt(menu1.scrollTop, 10)/32) + (document.getElementById("myRange").value/1)) + 'px';
                    innermenu1.style.left = ((document.getElementById("myRange").value/2) - 175) + 'px';
                }
            }
            innermenu1.style.top = menu1.scrollTop + tempvalue + 'px';

            document.getElementById("myRange").oninput = function() {
                document.getElementById("imageWidth").style.width = this.value + "px";
                innermenu1.style.left = ((document.getElementById("myRange").value/2) - 175) + 'px';
            }
            document.getElementById("textinput1").oninput = function() {
                document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = this.value;
            }
            document.getElementById("myRange2").oninput = function() {
                document.getElementById("text1").style.fontSize = this.value + "px";
            }
```